# Use multiple fields for mailto: link in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, url, gridview

I'm trying to build a gridview field that displays a name and links to an email address with a subject. I first tried to make this work using DataNavigateUrlFormatString, but apparently using a : in a DataNavigateUrlFormatString breaks the link, so unfortunately the code below leaves me with an empty link.

```
string[] UrlFields = { "bidd_name", "Email", "bidd_number", "bidd_desc", "Bidds_id" };
LinkField = new HyperLinkField();

LinkField.HeaderText = "Buyer";
LinkField.DataTextField = "buyer";
LinkField.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "GVpadding";
LinkField.ItemStyle.CssClass = "GVpadding";
LinkField.DataNavigateUrlFields = UrlFields;
LinkField.DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "mailto:{1} ?subject={2} {3}";
```

Next I tried using Eval() and NavigateUrl, but the code below gives me this error "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control."

```
EmailLinkField.NavigateUrl = "mailto:" + (string)Eval("Email") + "?subject=" + (string)Eval("bidd_number") + " " + (string)Eval("bidd_desc");
```

I did a little research on the error and found out that I might have to use a RowDataBound method, but I'm not sure how to go about this. Could calling the method below after building out the field change the URL to the desired value?

```
protected void grddata_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HyperLink hyp = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("EmailLinkField");
            hyp.NavigateUrl = "mailto:" + (string)Eval("Email") + "?subject=" + (string)Eval("bidd_number") + " " + (string)Eval("bidd_desc");
        }
    }
```

If so, how do I go about calling it? I'm not sure what parameters I need to use with it when doing something like this.

```
grddata_RowDataBound(null, null);
```

Using the nulls generates a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error and I don't know what value the sender or e should be.

If anybody could help me get these emails links generated it would be greatly appreciated. I have very little experience with C#, and haven't done all that much coding in general, so feel free to treat me like a child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use a templated column will fix your issue

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx

Comment: Thanks! This pointed me in the right direction. I was able to resolve my issue by adding the template field on the aspx page and then rearranging the order of the columns in the code behind page to ensure that the tables still look the same.